# Parsing a non-nested JSON string in Google Sheets using formulas only

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter, regexextract, json

I have a cell with the following JSON data:

```
{"rev2_0": "2,058", "rev2_1": "2,099", "rev2_2": "2,141", "rev2_3": "2,184", "revchg3_0": "3%", "revchg3_1": "6%"}
```

In another cell, I want to get the value of `rev2_1` but I don't want to run a script. I just want to use the built-in formulas to get it.

Comment: I think that this question should not be moved from SO as google sheets formulas are on topic there too. By the other hand this is not really a good question as it doesn't describe the search/research efforts made so far. Anyway, I added an answer b/c the previous answers were too convoluted for something that could be done with a short formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the value of `rev2_1` always will have 5 characters use

```
=mid(A1,find("rev2_1",A1)+10,5)
```

Explanation

- `find` finds the position of the first character of `rev2_1`
- `mid` gets a text (substring) of certain length (5) from a starting position, in this case the result of find plus 10 characters.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a shorter way, such as with string manipulation (e.g., MID) or regular expressions (REGEXEXTRACT), but this works:

```
=1*trim(substitute(substitute(substitute(index(SPLIT(A1,":"),3),"rev2_2",""),CHAR(34),""),",",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

**short formulas:**

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"_1""\: ""(.{5})")

=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"_1""\: (.{7})")

=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"rev2_1""\: ""(.{5})")

=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"rev2_1""\: (.{7})")

=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"rev2_1""\: ""(.+)\"", ""rev2_2")

=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"rev2_1""\: (.+)\, ""rev2_2")

=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"_1""\: ""(.+)\"", ""rev2_2")

=MID(A1;32;5)
```

[image: 0]

---

**this will search for what is in A5 cell:**

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1; ", "; "×"); "×")); ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&A5&"*";
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1; ", "; "×"); "×"))))); ": (.+)")
```

[image: 0]

---

**to remove doublequotes:**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1; ", "; "×"); "×")); ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&A5&"*";
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1; ", "; "×"); "×"))))); ": (.+)"); """"; "")
```

[image: 0]

---

**to convert it on number:**

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1; ", "; "×"); "×")); ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&A5&"*";
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1; ", "; "×"); "×"))))); ": (.+)"); """"; ""); ","; "."))
```

[image: 0]

---

**or:**

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1; ", "; "×"); "×")); ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&A5&"*";
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1; ", "; "×"); "×"))))); ": (.+)"); ","; ""); "\d+")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: @jason answer updated. if none of this helped please provide some explanation what exactly are you after